# Remove button field of a field generated by AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

This is my custom Drupal module. I have a form containing text fields, each with a button to remove the field from the form. The problem is that the remove button always removes the last field, regardless of which I press,

I am aware of increasing the variable `$form['incremento']['telefono']` but I can't find a solution.

```
/**
 *_permission
 */
function formOnigPreventivoTendaggi_permission() {
    return array(
        'permessi form_onig_preventivo_tendaggi' => array(
            'title' => t('Permetti la creazione del preventivo Tendaggi')
        )
    );
}
/**
 *_menù
 */
function formOnigPreventivoTendaggi_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['form/preventivo/tendaggi'] = array(
        'title' => 'Preventivo Onig Tendaggi',
        'access arguments' => array(
            'permessi form_onig_preventivo_tendaggi'
        ),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'page arguments' => array(
            'formOnigPreventivoTendaggi_form'
        )
    );
    return $items;
}
/**
 *_form
 */
function formOnigPreventivoTendaggi_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $incr = 0;
    if (!isset($form_state['incremento']['telefono'])) {
        $form_state['incremento']['telefono'] = 0;
    }
    $form['telefono'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#tree' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="telefono">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );
    if ($form_state['incremento']['telefono']) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['incremento']['telefono']; $i++) {
            $form['telefono'][$i]['campoTelefono']   = array(
                '#title' => t('Telefono'),
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#id' => 'campo-telefono' . $i
            );
            $form['telefono'][$i]['eliminaTelefono'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t('Elimina'),
                '#submit' => array(
                    'funzioneEliminaTelefono'
                ),
                '#id' => 'bottone-elimina-telefono' . $i,
                '#ajax' => array(
                    'callback' => 'chiamataAjax_telefono',
                    'wrapper' => 'telefono'
                )
            );
        }
    }
    $form['aggiungiTelefono'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Aggiungi'),
        '#submit' => array(
            'funzioneAggiungiTelefono'
        ),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'chiamataAjax_telefono',
            'wrapper' => 'telefono'
        ),
    );
    $form['Crea Preventivo']  = array(
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#type' => 'submit'
    );
    return $form;
}
/**
 *AJAX
 */
function chiamataAjax_telefono($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['telefono'];
}
function funzioneAggiungiTelefono($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['incremento']['telefono']++;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
function funzioneEliminaTelefono($form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
    if ($form_state['incremento']['telefono'] > 1) {
        $form_state['incremento']['telefono']--;
    }
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
function formOnigPreventivoTendaggi_form_submit() {

}
```